# How do i acess a nested hash map value that i have return from another class ? Java

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I am new to hash mapping and I was trying to created a nested hash map on one side of the class and create another class to call it out, so here's how my code looks like

```
public class Hash {
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> wow = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

    public void SetHash(){
        wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, Object>());
        wow.get("key").put("key2", "val2");
    }

    public HashMap GetMap(){
        return wow;
    }
}
```

And on the other class which is the main class it will be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Hash h = new Hash();
   h.SetHash();
   System.out.println(h.GetMap.get("key").get("key2"));
}
```

But when I place the second get, there's an error, so I am not sure if this is possible or if I should actually place the hash directly at the main class.

Comment: You miss the parentheses on the method call `GetMap()` .

Comment: Also the standard naming convention would be to start method names, including getters with a lower case letter. Furthermore you shouldn't hide the type arguments in the return type of the getter. There are some type checks that the compiler cannot do this way and also the second `get` won't work if you don't do this (even after fixing the method call as mentioned by Berger), since the compiler doesn't know the value type of the map is a map.

Comment: You should also avoid double referring the generic types of a collection in the right side of the expression. Instead, use an empty diamond operator like this: `private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> wow = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetMap` is a method, not an attribute, so you have to refer it with parenthesis `()`:

```
h.GetMap().get("key")
```

Now, second error. Your `Map<String, Map<String, String>` named `wow` contains a values that are objects of the type `Map<String, String>` so, before the get, you need get the map:

```
Map<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) h.GetMap().get("key");
```

And then you can print it:

```
System.out.println(m.get("key2"));
```

---

if you want an **ONELINER** (is not really clear, but check explanation in comments):

```
System.out.println(((HashMap<String, String>) h.GetMap().get("key")).get("key2"));
//                  ↑ casting  parenthesis  ↑ (
//                 ↑ this say group IS a map and allow get()       ↑
//                ↑ system.out.println parenthesis                              ↑
```

---

**NOTE:** change also this declaration

```
wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

By

```
wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, String>());
```

---

**FINAL CODE:**

```
public class Q37066776 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hash h = new Hash();
        h.SetHash();
        Map<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) h.GetMap().get("key");
        System.out.println(m.get("key2"));
    }

}

class Hash {
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> wow = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

    public void SetHash() {
        wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, String>());
        wow.get("key").put("key2", "val2");
    }

    public HashMap GetMap() {
        return wow;
    }
}
```

---

[**WORKING ONLINE DEMO**](https://ideone.com/wQXWX6)

---

---

but you can always

## Do it better! :=)

As pointed by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363967/andrew-williamson)

> - you can change return of the method,

But also many other things like:

- using less concrete objects  (`Map` instead of `HashMap`)
- follow conventions (`GetMap()` would be `getMap()`)
- Make `Hash` a `static` class with `static` block

If I had to *rewrite* your code, my result would be like this:

```
public class Q37066776 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Hash.getMap().get("key").get("key2"));
    }

}

class Hash {
    private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> wow = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    static {
        wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, String>());
        wow.get("key").put("key2", "val2");
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> getMap() {
        return wow;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can declare `GetMap()` as returning a `HashMap<String, String>`, rather than casting a raw type. This will remove the compilation warnings about using a raw type as well.

Comment: not really, you can declare `GetMap()` maybe returning `Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>`

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson please kindly check my last update

Comment: +1 for the fix. I'm not sure I would be advocating the `static` block though, that logic should probably be in the `main` method. That's just an opinion though.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson if the filling of the `Map` is in the `Main` class `static` block won't have much sense, but OP fill `Map` in the `setter` and this does not seem a good idea for me.. that's why I used the `static` block

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to refactor it, that's why I add the disclaimer of _that's just an opinion_.

Comment: Wow thanks guys , this is really concise but at my current level it would take me some time to digest this whole solution but it works so thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 errors:

1. GetMap is a method - you need to write GetMap().
2. you declared the inner Map as `HashMap<String, String>` - you cannot initialize the inner map to: `wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, Object>());`
   Change it to `wow.put("key", new HashMap<String, String>());`
3. In order to access the inner map from the main - you must declare the returned value of GetMap to be `Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>` instead of just raw type. Otherwise, the outer class won't know that the outer map value is also a hash map.

Instead of using nested maps, you should use google's Guava Table:
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html